# Single quotes faster than double quotes?

Tags: javascript, string

I was wondering which quotes I should use for strings in JavaScript. I tend to use single quotes, but use double quotes depending on the scenario ("I'm pregnant!"). I ran a JavaScript performance test, and it appears single quotes are faster?

[Performance Test Link](http://jsperf.com/singlevsdouble)

Does anyone know why single quotes would be faster???

[image: Proof]
[image: Proof 2]

Comment: That absolutely sounds like it has the makings for a great urban legend...

Comment: They aren’t. They really aren’t.

Comment: That code is probably going to just degenerate into nothing, since it's just a simple variable assignment that any decent runtime can determine to be dead code.

Comment: What results do you get if you reverse the order of the tests?

Comment: In Firefox, doubles are slightly faster, but not in IE or Chrome

Comment: Of course they are. They have twice less quotes than double. It's only logical.

Comment: Time to refactor every string I've ever written in JS.

Comment: @HackedByChinese, you should do the same for your html strings as well just to make sure

Comment: In a test with other operations, no significant performance changes were visible: http://jsperf.com/singlequotes-vs-doublequotes

Comment: @PitaJ View edit above please.

Comment: you are asking about at noise, not meaningful results.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let’s take the numbers in your screenshot as an example.

- single quotes: 711,222,327 ops/sec, ±0.27%.
- double quotes: 708,941,116 ops/sec, ±0.31%.

They differ from their average by 0.1%, which is **less than they vary between runs**. The results placing one over another aren’t meaningful. As to why they vary between runs: empty loops are fast and can be influenced a lot by your CPU changing clock speeds to adjust to temperature, or background processes, or butterflies from the other side of the world.